# Tibco client ignoring expired certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, tibco

I'm trying to understand why one tibco client is ignoring an expired server certificate. I read about ssl_verify_host and ssl_verify_hostname and I must say I find it's a bit confusing:

> - ssl_verify_host Specifies whether the client should verify the server’s certificate. The values for this parameter are enabled or
>     disabled. By default, this parameter is enabled, signifying the client
>     should verify the server’s certificate. When disabled, the client
>     establishes secure communication with the server, but does not verify
>     the server’s identity.
> - ssl_verify_hostname Specifies whether the client should verify the name in the CN field of the server’s certificate. The values for
>     this parameter are enabled and disabled. By default, this parameter is
>     enabled, signifying the client should verify the name of the connected
>     host or the name specified in the ssl_expected_hostname parameter
>     against the value in the server’s certificate. If the names do not
>     match, the client rejects the connection. When disabled, the client establishes secure communication with the server, but does not verify the server’s name.

I guess by "does not verify the server's identity" they mean "client is not checking server certificate against root CA". This implies that client actually ignore completely the server certificate? (so it doesn't care if it's expired?)